# Problems using fgets multiple times

Tags: c

I am really new to C and I am facing a problem with fgets(). I need to make multiple calls to fgets in order to retrieve 4 pieces of data, a name, age, num1 and num2. I cannot use scanf for this I have to use fgets. However, I am facing problems when I make multiple calls to fgets. And just to clarify I want to read `num1` and `num2` as strings. Here is my code:

```
int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    /* code */
    char name[50];
    char ageString[3];
    char num1[6];
    char num2[6];

    printf("Enter your name: ");
    fgets(name, 50, stdin);
    printf("Enter an age: ");
    fgets(ageString, 3, stdin);
    printf("Enter num 1: ");
    fgets(num1, 6, stdin);
    printf("Enter num 2: ");
    fgets(num2, 6, stdin);


    // replace the trailing '\n' with '\0'
    name[strcspn(name, "\n")] = '\0';
    ageString[strcspn(ageString, "\n")] = '\0';
    num1[strcspn(num1, "\n")] = '\0';
    num2[strcspn(num2, "\n")] = '\0';

    printf("Your name is: %s, you are %s years old, num1: %s, num2: %s\n", name, ageString, num1, num2);

    return 0;
}
```

Here is what I get outputted in the terminal:

```
Enter your name: Random
Enter an age: 21
Enter num 1: Enter num 2: 1
Your name is: Random, you are 21 years old, num1: , num2: 1
```

The program reads name and age fine but the num1 is not being read and the formatting is really off.

If anyone has a fix for this that would be greatly appreciated. Again, I am very new to C so I am still learning.

Thank you!

Comment: Don't be mean with the string lengths: `char ageString[3];` can hold `1\n\0` which is pretty useless. Make them all size 100, say, and remember that `fgets()` retains the newline, if there is room. There *wasn't* room with age `21` so the newline was left in the input for the next entry.

Comment: When the input stream contains "21\n" and `fgets` is called with `3` as the size, it reads 2 characters and stores `21\0` in the buffer.  The `\n` is still in the input stream.  The next call to `fgets` reads only the newline.  Instead of blindly assuming that there is a newline in the buffer, you should check.

Comment: Thank you! @WeatherVane this was indeed what was going wrong. I fixed it and made the size bigger and its working now :)

Comment: Thank you @WilliamPursell, I did this and its working now!

Comment: LESSON: *Don't Skimp on Buffer Size....*

Comment: I posted the answer in the comments to a answer post for future users.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that your array sizes are too small. When you type in "21\n" and `fgets` is called with 3 as the size, it reads 2 characters (not 3) The \n remains, so `fgets` next reads only the newline. The solution would be to to increase your array size by one (for that specific input) or *"Don't skimp on Buffer Size...."* (@David C. Rankin)